# Why object array become null when do Promise inside loop

Tags: node.js

code below will return [{}]

what wrong from the code below?

```
 fileId.forEach((element) => {
        getFileFromCloud(element)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
                x.v.push({ dataUrl: result });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err.message);
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a list of promises and then do a Promise.all to get the array of results.

I would suggest using the async/await syntax to get the results from the Promise.all call, I believe this is a lot more readable.

You could also do Promise.all(promises).then(resultList => .....

This can be used to populate the x.v array.

```js
const fileId = [0,1,2,3];
const x = {
 v: []
};

async function getFileFromCloud(element) {
    return { fileId: element, data: "some data" };
}

async function testDownload() {
  let promises = fileId.map((element) => {
       return getFileFromCloud(element)
              .then((result) => {
                  return ({ dataUrl: result });
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                  console.log(err.message);
                  throw err; // Throw to keep promise chain intact.
              });
  });

  let resultList = await Promise.all(promises);
  // Append to the x.v array.
  x.v = x.v.concat(resultList);
  console.log("x.v:", x.v);
}

testDownload();
```

Comment: Great! Hope it helps!